# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery with requirejs

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, requirejs

I am getting this error that says jQuery is not defined.

bootstrap.js:8 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuerybootstrap.js:8 (anonymous function)

Bootstrap v3.3.0

jQuery JavaScript Library v2.1.3

requirejs

```
 require.config({
shim: {
    'backbone': {
        deps: ['underscore', 'jquery']
    },
    'backbone-validation': {
        deps: ['backbone', 'jquery']
    },
    'jquerymx': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    },
    'bootstrap': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
},
paths: {
    'jquery': '/public/js/lib/jquery-2.1.3',
    'jquerymx': '/public/js/lib/jquerymx-3.2.custom',
    'bootstrap': '/public/js/lib/bootstrap',
    'handlebars': '/public/js/lib/handlebars-v2.0.0',
    'underscore': '/public/js/lib/underscore',
    'backbone': '/public/js/lib/backbone',
    'backbone-validation': '/public/js/lib/backbone-validation'
}
});
require(
[
    'order!jquery',
    'order!jquerymx',
    'order!bootstrap',
    'order!handlebars',
    'order!underscore',
    'order!backbone',
    'order!backbone-validation'
], function () {

    require(['main'], function (main) {
        main.initialize();
    });
});
```

is there something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

First, the `order` plugin is no longer supported or necessary in RequireJS 2.0.  The `shim` configuration is fully capable of expressing what you need to do.  [See here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Upgrading-to-RequireJS-2.0#shim-config-)  for details.

Second, I'm a little confused why you have both `jquery` and `jquery.min` listed as dependencies.  They should provide the exact same thing, with `jquery.min` just being a smaller file.  Some JS can get confused when you pull in the same code twice, which might be what's happening here.  Try removing all instances of `jquery.min` from your configuration.

Finally, your two-phased `require(...)` call doesn't appear to be necessary.  Assuming your `main` module lists the libraries it needs directly, you should be able to just do:

```
require(['main'], function (main) {
    main.initialize();
});
```

If the above suggestions don't help, please provide more details -- i.e. what is in the `main` module.