# Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

First of all, thanks for your time looking at my problem!
Seccond, I have seen other questions like mine (for example:
[Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery with requirejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29316204/uncaught-error-bootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery-with-requirejs)), but they didn't awnser my question.

So, here is the `<head>` of my `<html>`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <!-- metadata -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <!-- responsive -->
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <!-- [/] responsive -->

    <!-- [/] metadata -->




    <!-- links -->

        <!-- bootstrap -->

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- [/] bootstrap -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- [/] links -->




    <!-- script -->
    <!--<script src="js/action.js"></script>-->

        <!-- jquery -->
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <!-- [/] jquery -->

        <!-- bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- [/] bootstrap -->

    <!-- [/] script -->




    <title>standaard html</title>

</head>




<body>

    <!-- hoofdnavigatie -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top      bas_hoofdnav">

        <!-- logo in menubalk -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">

            <img src="afb/logo/logo.png" class="bas_hoofdnav_logo" alt="Brand" >

        </a>
        <!-- [/] logo in menubalk -->




        <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-right       bas_hoofdnav_knoppen">

            <li role="presentation" class="active       bas_hoofdnav_knp_actief"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">start</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">over ons</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">diensten</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">winkel</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#">contact</a></li>

        </ul>

    </nav>
    <!-- [/] hoofdnavigatie -->

</body>
```

as you can see I have included jquery and the bootstrap links. but even so... I get this error message: 
`Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6`

[and here the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usen3.png)

Do I miss something here?

Comment: move jquery before boostrap.

Comment: hahaha... so logical. THANKS a lot!! that did the trick ;)

Answer (score 23):

As I can see in your code you have added jquery Js after the Bootstrap js. You need to include jquery js before adding bootstrap js. Your problem will fix, because bootstrap requires Jquery file.

```
<!-- First include jquery js -->
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<!-- Then include bootstrap js -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: ha ha ha ha really joss answer

Answer (score 9):

You need to put jQuery above the Bootstrap JS.

```
    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- [/] jquery -->

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- [/] bootstrap -->
```

Answer (score 5):

After sure you included `jquery` library and `bootstrap`  using these commands?:

First, install jQuery using npm as follows:
`npm install jquery --save`
Second, install Bootstrap using npm as follows:
`npm install --save bootstrap@3`

My problem was in  :

`angular.json` just change sorting for scripts files included under `project` .

```
     "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
        ]
```

to be like this :

```
     "scripts": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
           "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
        ]
```

Comment: This fixed my issue